# Perform CHIP-qPCR to detect Myc

Tags: histone-deacetylase

I use Panobinostat (HDAC inhibitor) to treat the GBM cells. I saw Myc protein level go down but not mRNA level. Panobinostat is known to inhibit HDAC1 and HDAC2. HDAC2 gene belongs to the histone deacetylase class of enzymes responsible for the removal of acetyl groups from lysine residues at the N-terminal region of the core histones.

I performed HDAC2-CHIP-qPCR in GBM cells treated with DMSO or Panobinostat. When I run CHIP-qPCR for Myc promoter region. I didnt observe any changes in Myc expression level.

1. A person asked me that Panobinostat reduce HDAC2. I immunoprecipitated HDAC2, why I didnt observe a reduction of Myc DNA level.

I answered that the dose for Panobinostat is not sufficient for the dissociation between HDAC2 and Myc promoter region so there is no change in Myc DNA level (I also did not observe a reduction of mRNA level upon Panobinostat treatment).

2. That person asked why the western blot showed a reduction of HDAC2? If HDAC2 is down the Myc DNA level must be down. It means that the HDAC2 antibody is not specific or I did something wrong.

I answered that the HDAC2 protein could be reduced in the cytoplasm but not in the histon.

Does my answers correct?